# MySQL: select last set of records in each month

Tags: mysql

Several times per month, a new volley of records is added to the table certificant_region_stats with an identical timestamp, certificants_modified. I'm trying to select all records from the last volley per month.

My attempts crash my console:

```
SELECT * 
FROM certificant_region_stats 
WHERE certificants_modified
    IN (
        SELECT   MAX(certificants_modified)
        FROM     certificant_region_stats
        GROUP BY YEAR(certificants_modified), MONTH(certificants_modified)
    ) 
ORDER BY certificants_modified DESC;
```

The subquery works fine on its own, so I'm guessing I'm using IN wrong?

EDIT: sample data

```
| id | country | certificants_number | certificants_modified | 
==============================================================
| 1  | USA     | 2                   | 2015-06-22 10:24:55   |
| 2  | Canada  | 4                   | 2015-06-22 10:24:55   |
| 3  | USA     | 5                   | 2015-06-09 09:18:24   |
| 4  | Canada  | 6                   | 2015-06-09 09:18:24   |
| 5  | USA     | 8                   | 2015-05-15 11:30:00   |
| 6  | Canada  | 8                   | 2015-05-15 11:30:00   |
| 7  | USA     | 3                   | 2015-05-02 08:45:01   |
| 8  | Canada  | 7                   | 2015-05-02 08:45:01   |
```

I'd expect it to return * from rows 1, 2, 5 and 6.

Comment: Please post a small sample of rows from the `certificant_region_stats` table together with what you expect the query output to be. It isn't clear if the `certificants_modified` value is unique, or if the combination of that value along with the dates makes it unique.

Comment: What does "crash my console" exactly mean? As I see it, your query is perfect for the task at hand. An index on certificants_modified should prove useful, by the way.

Comment: Your query works fine:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b386/4/0

Answer (score 0):

One good strategy to `SELECT` the best row within a group is to `LEFT JOIN` a table to itself with all the group columns equal and then find a row that has no better row. It might look like this:

```
SELECT crs.*
FROM certificant_region_stats AS crs
LEFT JOIN certificant_region_stats AS better
ON YEAR(crs.certificants_modified) = YEAR(better.certificants_modified)
   AND MONTH(crs.certificants_modified) = MONTH(better.certificants_modified)
   AND crs.country = better.country
   AND crs.certificants_modified < better.certificants_modified
WHERE better.id IS NULL
```

Or you can use the [`LAST_DAY` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) to keep the year and month and discard the day and time, like so:

```
SELECT crs.*
FROM certificant_region_stats AS crs
LEFT JOIN certificant_region_stats AS better
ON LAST_DAY(crs.certificants_modified) = LAST_DAY(better.certificants_modified)
   AND crs.country = better.country
   AND crs.certificants_modified < better.certificants_modified
WHERE better.id IS NULL
```

<sub>Code in this answer is dual licensed: [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) or the [MIT License as published by OSI](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. It uses an expression to grab the first day of each month, then extracts your last batch of data for that month.

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_FORMAT(crs.certificants_modified, '%Y-%m-01')) month_begin,
       crs.id, crs.country, crs.certificants_modified
  FROM certificant_region_stats crs
  JOIN (
       SELECT MAX(certificants_modified) lastmod,
              DATE(DATE_FORMAT(certificants_modified, '%Y-%m-01')) month_begin
         FROM certificant_region_stats
        GROUP BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(certificants_modified, '%Y-%m-01'))
        ) last ON crs.certificants_modified = last.lastmod
 ORDER BY month_begin, crs.id
```

See this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b386/3/0